# Actualización de Base de datos mysql con php

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Tengo un archivo Score.php para realizar update a un campo llamado score de tipo entero en una base de datos mysql:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "matgic");

    $id_user = $_POST["id_user"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $score = $_POST["score"];


    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE user SET score=? WHERE id_user = ? AND username =?");


    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "isi",$id_user, $username,$score);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);


    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false; 


    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement))
    {
        $response["success"] = true; 
        $response["user_id"] = $user_id; 
        $response["name"] = $name;
        $response["username"] = $username;
        $response["password"] = $password;
        $response["date"] = $date;
        $response["email"] = $email;
        $response["score"] = $score;
        }

    echo json_encode($response);
```

La clase en android studio que invoca a ese archivo php es:

```
public class ScoreRequest extends StringRequest
{

    private static final String Score_Request_URL="http://192.168.1.221/Score.php";//declaramos una constante
    private Map<String, String> params;

    //constructor de la clase
    public ScoreRequest (int id_user, String username, int score, Response.Listener<String> listener)
    {
        super(Request.Method.POST,Score_Request_URL,listener, null);
        params= new HashMap<>();
        params.put("id_user", id_user+"");
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("score", score+"");


    }//fin de constructor



    @Override
    public Map <String, String> getParams()
    {
        return params;
    }//fin de método Map


}//fin de clase
```

también tengo el activity2.java donde necesito que cuando presione un Button llamado btnno realice la actualización en la base de datos del campo llamado score, y al mismo tiempo me conduzca a otro activity2 con el campo score actualizado ya que le sumo 1.

el codigo del método del Button (btnno) en activity es:

```
btnno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            int scoreaux;
            scoreaux=Integer.parseInt(score);
            scoreaux+=1;
            final String usernameaux=username;
            final int useraux=Integer.parseInt(userid);


            Response.Listener<String> responseListener= new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse=new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success= jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if(success)
                        {



                           int user=jsonResponse.getInt("id_user");
                           String nameuser=jsonResponse.getString("username");
                           int scoreb=jsonResponse.getInt("score");


                            Intent intent=new Intent (Digits.this, Digits2.class);

                           intent.putExtra("id_user", user);
                            intent.putExtra("username", nameuser);
                           intent.putExtra("score", scoreb);




                            Digits.this.startActivity(intent);


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Digits.this);
                            builder.setMessage("User or Id incorrect")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create().show();
                        }
                    }

                    catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }//fin de método onResponse
            };//fin de Response.Listener<String>

            ScoreRequest scoreRequest= new ScoreRequest(useraux,usernameaux,scoreaux, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(Digits.this);
            queue.add(scoreRequest);

        }//fin de onclick
    });//fin de setOnClickListener

    //fin de método btnno
```

y el codigo de activity2 es:

```
public class Digits2 extends AppCompatActivity
{
    String username;
    int userid, score;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_digits2);

        Intent intent =getIntent();
        score=intent.getIntExtra("score",-1);
        username=intent.getStringExtra("username");
        userid=intent.getIntExtra("id_user",-1);
    }
}
```

cuando ejecuto el php en el navegador me devuelve esto:

> Notice: Undefined index: id_user in C:\xampp\htdocs\Score.php on line
>   4
>
> Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Score.php on line
>   5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: score in C:\xampp\htdocs\Score.php on line 6
>   {"success":false}

El problema es que cuando ejecuto la aplicación no ingresa al success porque coge el else y devuelve el AlertDialog con "User o id incorrect", por lo poco que entiendo la consulta esta retornando false, pero no se la razón, de antemano gracias por su valioso tiempo.

Comment: Agrega un break-point en la línea: `boolean success= jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");` y revisa el valor de _jsonResponse_  o has un `Log.i("MiTag", "El valor retornado es:" + jsonResponse);` justo antes de verificar si trae un success (Esto lo revisas en el LogCat). Lo anterior es para ver que resultado esta retornando.

Comment: Gustavo, hice debug y he colocado el punto de interrupción que me has dicho y esto devuelve response="{succes":false} \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n

Comment: también agregue la linea Log.i("MiTag", "El valor retornado es:" + jsonResponse); y esto me devuelve: El valor retornado es:{"success":false}

Comment: Sergio los `Notice: Undefined index` indican que no se están enviando los datos que intentas pasar en `params`. El mapa debe ser llenado en el método `getParams()`, no después de invocar a `super(...)`.

Comment: A. Cedano gracias por tu apoyo, hice lo que me has dicho pero aún tiene el problema, seguire intentado

Comment: A todos, gracias por su invaluable ayuda, por si a alguien le es útil asi lo solucioné, resultó que en el archivo Score.php en la linea mysqli_prepare el orden de las variables es score, id_user, username y en la linea mysqli_stmt_bind_param tenia "isi", cuando debe ser "iis" por el orden de las variables de derecha a izquierda en la sentencia mysqli_prepare. Así también la linea mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $user_id, $name, $username, $password, $date, $email, $score); la suprimí ya que es UPDATE la sentencia y no insert o delete.